# Regular Expression for accepting phone numbers

Tags: java, python, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

I need a regular expression that accepts all following phone number formats:

+1-650-123-0123

(650) 123 0123

(650) 123-0123

(+1): 650-123-0123

(+1) 650 123 0123

I currently have the following regular expression:

```
\(?\+?[0-9]?\)?-?\(?(\d{3})\)?(\s|-)+(\d{3})(\s|-)+(\d{4})
```

The problem I currently have is that it accepts most of them, but not the following: (650)123-0123. The part in the middle ((\s|-)+) should only match if it found (xyz).. How can I do this? I tried doing a lookahead/lookbehind, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation).

Comment: @edmastermind29, This is not what he wants. He has to *validate* given phone number, not *normailze* it.

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like you are expecting a whitespace or - after the (650) with (\s|-)+

Comment: You can use multiple regexp and OR them.  In some cases multiple simple regexp are easier to debug.

Comment: Yes, but I only want a whitespace or - if it found an occurence of something like (650) before.. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

There is a [project on Google code](http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) that has solved your problem for you!

Their solution has been [ported to Python](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers).

> ### Highlights of functionality
>
> Parsing/formatting/validating phone numbers for all countries/regions
>   of the world.
>
> `getNumberType` - gets the type of the number based on the
>   number itself; able to distinguish Fixed-line, Mobile, Toll-free,
>   Premium Rate, Shared Cost, VoIP and Personal Numbers (whenever
>   feasible).
>
> `isNumberMatch` - gets a confidence level on whether two
>   numbers could be the same.
>
> `getExampleNumber`/`getExampleNumberByType` -
>   provides valid example numbers for all countries/regions, with the
>   option of specifying which type of example phone number is needed.
>
> `isPossibleNumber` - quickly guessing whether a number is a possible
>   phonenumber by using only the length information, much faster than a
>   full validation.
>
> `isValidNumber` - full validation of a phone number for
>   a region using length and prefix information.
>
> `AsYouTypeFormatter` -
>   formats phone numbers on-the-fly when users enter each digit.
>
> `findNumbers` - finds numbers in text input.
>
> `PhoneNumberOfflineGeocoder`
>   - provides geographical information related to a phone number.

Comment: @casperOne: I think it's actually a Google library... I may well be wrong though!

Comment: Only rephrased it so that it doesn't come across as "LMGTFY" which would draw flags/delete votes. =)

Answer (score 1):

You could use conditional look aheads like `(?(?=regex)then|else)` but AFAIK Java's standard regex engine doesn't support those.

Alternatively build a couple of expressions and test if any one of them matches. This would make reading/writing the expressions easier and might not even have a noticable performance hit. If you need all those in a single expression try something like this:

```
^expression1$|^expression2$|...
```

Note, however, that this *might* result in some problems if the expressions get too complicated (some JVM versions seem to have difficulties with the `|` (or) expressions.

Comment: Yeah.. I thought about building a couple of expressions. It looks like Java doesn't support look aheads.. Thanks.

Comment: @durplr Java supports look aheads but it doesn't support conditions based on look aheads.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my source below. That will give you many starting points in which to construct your regex for phone numbers.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation) is my source.

Comment: Copy paste is not good excercise.

Comment: I don't want a completely new regular expression. I want my thought process and add a few things or change something so that it works. Copying your regex won't help me. The whole idea is that I learn how to fix my final regular expression. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: @durplr You're welcome. I believe its a starting point that leads to fixing your regex. You can use [this](http://regexpal.com/) to test what you come up with.